# How to get number of port, status Port in Cisco using TCPClient?

Tags: c#, telnet, tcpclient, cisco

I telnet to my Cisco equipment, everything is ok, using TCPClient Cisco respond bytes array I can get and Encoding to String.

Sending and receiving work well, I receive everything Cisco responding to my RichtextBox..

Problem: I dont know how to show status of port, number of port and load them to TextBox, Combobox.

Is there anyway to get number of port and get their status then show to Control in WinForm (for example in Listview).

My Richtextbox has returned when I run 'show ip int bri'

```
FastEthernet0/1            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up      
FastEthernet0/2            unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
FastEthernet0/3            unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
FastEthernet0/4            unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
FastEthernet0/5            unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
FastEthernet0/6            unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
FastEthernet0/7            unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
FastEthernet0/8            unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
FastEthernet0/9            unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
 --More--         FastEthernet0/10           unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
FastEthernet0/11           unassigned      YES unset  down                  down    
FastEthernet0/12           unassigned      YES unset  down                  down
```

This is Button Show Port

```
private void btnShowPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            if (serverStream.CanWrite)
            {
                txtOutput.Enabled = true;
                byte[] outStream2 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("sh ip int br" + "\n"+" ");
                serverStream.Write(outStream2, 0, outStream2.Length);
                serverStream.Flush();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Server is not connected!");
                clientSocket.Close();
                serverStream.Close();
                return;
            }

            if (serverStream.CanRead)
            {

                AutoCloseMsgBox.Show("Show Port...", "Thong Bao", 1200);

                    byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    serverStream.Read(inStream,0,(int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
                    string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
                    Msg(returndata);  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            return;
        }
    }
```

My Richtextbox to show information Cisco sending

```
  public void Msg(string msg)
    { 
        this.txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text + msg;
        this.txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text.Replace("????????","Welcome Telnet Management");   
    }
```

Comment: post your code please, and remove all personal details (ip's, credentials,etc.)

Comment: I have posted my code above.

Comment: Does anyone know, help me please?

Comment: It seems that the solution is not one related to programming, but rather to cisco commands specifically. You will have better luck posting this question on SuperUser.com